# Правильное извлечение информации из htm Objective c

Tags: objective-c

Как правильно получить значение temp_c data = -10.Пытаюсь путем JSON. Не получается

```
NSString *city = _inputCityTextField.text;
    NSString *urlPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=%@", city];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlPath];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSDictionary *forcasting = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xml_api_reply version="1">
    <weather module_id="0" tab_id="0" mobile_row="0" mobile_zipped="1"
    row="0"section="0" >
<forecast_information>

<city data="Moscow"/>
<postal_code data="Moscow"/>

<latitude_e6 data=""/>

<longitude_e6 data=""/>

<forecast_date data="2011-01-20"/>

<current_date_time data="2011-01-20 18:00:00 +0000"/>

<unit_system data="SI"/>

</forecast_information>

<current_conditions>

<condition data="Небольшой снег"/>

<temp_f data="14"/>

<temp_c data="**-10**"/>

<humidity data="Влажность: 83 %"/>

<icon data="/ig/images/weather/flurries.gif"/>

<wind_condition data="Ветер: ЮВ, 1 м/с"/>

</current_conditions>

<forecast_conditions>

<day_of_week data="Чт"/>

<low data="-16"/>

<high data="-9"/>

<icon data="/ig/images/weather/snow.gif"/>

<condition data="Ливневый снег"/>

</forecast_conditions>

<forecast_conditions>

...

</forecast_conditions>

</weather>

</xml_api_reply>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете воспользоваться любой сторонней библиотекой для разбора XML, я могу показать на примере `XMLDictionary`, как Вам получить значение `temp_c`. Установить данную библиотеку легко, можете также воспользоваться CocoaPods. Затем подключите её:

```
#import "XMLDictionary/XMLDictionary.h"
```

И добавьте следующий код:

```
NSString* data = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\
<xml_api_reply version=\"1\">\
<weather module_id=\"0\" tab_id=\"0\" mobile_row=\"0\" mobile_zipped=\"1\" row=\"0\" section=\"0\" >\
<forecast_information>\
<city data=\"Moscow\"/>\
<postal_code data=\"Moscow\"/>\
<latitude_e6 data=\"\"/>\
<longitude_e6 data=\"\"/>\
<forecast_date data=\"2011-01-20\"/>\
<current_date_time data=\"2011-01-20 18:00:00 +0000\"/>\
<unit_system data=\"SI\"/>\
</forecast_information>\
<current_conditions>\
<condition data=\"Небольшой снег\"/>\
<temp_f data=\"14\"/>\
<temp_c data=\"**-10**\"/>\
<humidity data=\"Влажность: 83 %\"/>\
<icon data=\"/ig/images/weather/flurries.gif\"/>\
<wind_condition data=\"Ветер: ЮВ, 1 м/с\"/>\
</current_conditions>\
<forecast_conditions>\
<day_of_week data=\"Чт\"/>\
<low data=\"-16\"/>\
<high data=\"-9\"/>\
<icon data=\"/ig/images/weather/snow.gif\"/>\
<condition data=\"Ливневый снег\"/>\
</forecast_conditions>\
<forecast_conditions>\
</weather>\
</xml_api_reply>";
XMLDictionaryParser* parser = [[XMLDictionaryParser alloc] init];
NSDictionary* parsedData = [parser dictionaryWithString:data];
if (parsedData) {

    NSString* temp_c_value = parsedData[@"weather"][@"current_conditions"][@"temp_c"][@"_data"];
    NSLog(@"temp_c_value %@", temp_c_value);
}
```

Здесь я просто скопировал приведённую Вами в вопросе строчку в переменную data, однако Вы можете инициализовать данную переменную как угодно (Вы вроде бы данные через HTTP-запрос получаете).